# Showing dropdown menu using class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a menu and I am trying to make level 3 for this menu. I need to add a class "show-submenu" for the submenu whose parent the user hovered over and remove that class if the user hovered over another menu item or clicked outside the menu.
For this I use Jquery.

For example, if user hovers li with the Refund policy I need to add the "show-submenu" class to "dropdown-menu" with the Sample page
if user hovers li with the Test page I need to add "show-submenu" class to "dropdown-menu" with the Contact

html

```
<li  class="menu-item menu-item-has-children nav-item">
<a  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"class="dropdown-toggle nav-link show" >Pages</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu show">
        <li class="menu-item  nav-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/login-page/" class="dropdown-item">
                Login page
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/refund_returns/" class="dropdown-item">
                Refund policy
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li itemscope="itemscope" class="menu-item nav-item">
                    <a href="http://localhost/sample-page/" class="dropdown-item">
                        Sample page
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/home-logos/" class="dropdown-item">
                Test page
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="menu-item nav-item">
                    <a href="http://localhost/kontakt/" class="dropdown-item">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Jquery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var timeout;

  $('.dropdown-item').mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').find('.dropdown-menu').first().addClass('show-submenu');
  });

  $('.dropdown-item').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show-submenu');
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    // Check if the clicked element is outside the menu
    if (!target.closest('.dropdown-menu').length) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show-submenu');
    }
  });
});
```

this code has several bugs.

1. show-submenu added to "dropdown-menu show" (  ) but I need only one that belongs to current li
2. I need to have only 1 show-submenu and remove it if user hover another menu item

Comment: You description and code doesn't match. You said you need to add class when user hovers mouse. But in the code you are removing class.

Comment: Also what is the need for removing class on body click if you are removing class on mouse leave itself.

Comment: I'm trying to remove a class from the submenu that the user left the cursor on and add this class to the submenu that he hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add mouseenter and mouseleave on li element instead of dropdown-item so that it would stay visible even if you hover mouse to the child elements.

The below code will show the submenu when you hover the mouse and hide the same submenu when you leave the mouse from parent.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // add mouse event handler to show or hide
  $('.dropdown-item').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.menu-item').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show-submenu');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show-submenu');
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    // Check if the clicked element is outside the menu
    if (!target.closest('.dropdown-menu').length) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show-submenu');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.show, .show-submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children nav-item">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link show">Pages</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
      <li class="menu-item nav-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/login-page/" class="dropdown-item">
          Login page
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/refund_returns/" class="dropdown-item">
          Refund policy
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li itemscope="itemscope" class="menu-item nav-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/sample-page/" class="dropdown-item">
              Sample page
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown nav-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/home-logos/" class="dropdown-item">
          Test page
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="menu-item nav-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/kontakt/" class="dropdown-item">
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your `jQuery` code and this is working for me :

- It adds a `show-submenu` class to closest parent `dropdown-menu` when leaving focus on `dropdown-item`
- It removes all `show-submenu` classes on all `dropdown-menu` when entering focus on a `dropdown-item`
- It removes all `show-submenu` classes on all `dropdown-menu` when clicking away from the menu

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var timeout;
    
      $('.dropdown-item').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show-submenu');
      });
    
      $('.dropdown-item').mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show-submenu');
      });
    
      $(document).on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
    
        // Check if the clicked element is outside the menu
        if (!target.closest('.dropdown-menu').length) {
          $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show-submenu');
        }
      });
});
```

> `closest()` already get the first element that matches the selector by
> testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in
> the DOM tree

https://jsfiddle.net/bLsyrncz/44/